# JPA query returns not all values

Tags: sql, entity-framework, jpa

I have a table which has these values: id, product, productid, brand, description, sum, quantity.

```
7, December, 74909, Fuji, Good bicycle, 2000, 4
7, March, 74534, Giant, Good goof bicycle, 2000, 4
8, Winter, 83458, Ghost, Very Good bicycle, 5000, 2
8, Spring, 42144, Regis, Good bicycle, 92000, 7
8, Summer, 47122, Maxima, Good veryyy bicycle, 92000, 7
9, Okutava, 53681, Sunny, Good bicycle, 9000, 5
10, Pavilion, 94847, Eclipse, Good bicycle, 92000, 7
10, Cicso, 47465, Omega, Good bicycle, 92000, 7
11, Lenovo, 16611, Hemi Cuda, Good bicycle, 92000, 7
11, Coral, 14342, Mustang, Bad bicycle, 92000, 7
12, Duple, 22222, Pulsar, Normal bicycle, 92000, 7
12, Shimano, 52515, Skyline, Good bicycle, 92000, 7
13, Salaror, 14542, Silvia, Good bicycle, 92000, 7
14, Phone, 21876, Miata, Good bicycle, 92000, 7
14, Imago, 12111, Titan, Good bicycle, 92000, 7
15, Kubas, 43777, Celica, Good bicycle, 92000, 7
16, Iki, 65427, Civic, Good bicycle, 92000, 7
16, Maxima, 13999, Accord, Good bicycle, 92000, 7
```

I am using JPA query to return it.

```
@Entity
@Table(name="ITEMS")
@NamedQuery(name="returnItems",
            query="SELECT c FROM Items c WHERE c.id > 0")

    public class Items implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    private Integer id;
    private String product;
    private Integer productId;
    private String brand;
    private String description;
    private Integer sum;
    private Integer quantity;
```

But when I run it, I get wrong values:

```
7 December 74909 2000
7 December 74909 2000
8 Winter 83458 5000
8 Winter 83458 5000
8 Winter 83458 5000
9 Okutava 53681 9000
10 Pavilion 94847 92000
10 Pavilion 94847 92000
11 Lenovo 16611 92000
11 Lenovo 16611 92000
12 Duple 22222 92000
12 Duple 22222 92000
13 Salaror 14542 92000
14 Phone 21876 92000
14 Phone 21876 92000
15 Kubas 43777 92000
16 Iki 65427 92000
16 Iki 65427 92000
```

The problem is when I run query it do not print all values from database as you can see.

However when I run:

```
@NamedQuery(name="returnItems",
        query="SELECT c FROM Items c WHERE c.product = 'Maxima'")
```

It gives me a value 'Maxima' which is not in the previous list.

Someone has any issues?

Comment: please clarify what you mean by wrong values

Comment: If you just add the first rows of your result and instead the implementation of your model classes, it is easier to help you (at least next time). I'm sure the downvote will vanish in that case.

Comment: I've given you an answer already - just by guessing your model classes. As you can see - it would have helped if you would have shown your `@Id` attribute. For JPA questions you can forget about the simple setter/getters - but it is always important to see _all_ JPA annotations you used for your model class (even those on the attributes). And no - you did not write what is wrong - you just showed your result and we had to guess what is wrong.

Comment: You should go through a JPA tutorial or a book.

Comment: This was a friendly advice, really. Nobody can help you if you are not familiar with the basics of the tool you are using. The structure of your question can be considered a little bit insulting. Firstly, you are forcing us to find the difference. All rows are there but columns are missing; why are you lazy to write it? Secondly, you said _"the query does not print all values..."_ Queries are executed, they don't print anything. Actually, I am sure that when you take a look at the code that prints this (you didn't show it), you'll figure out the answer to this question yourself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The column that you are calling `id` is not a real id - it is not a primary key (which is unique for all rows). And because the JPA provider is caching the entities for an id, it returns the same entity for all rows with the same id.

You have to use a table model where you have a unique primary key column and map that column to the attribute with the `@Id` annotation. Or if you want to have a primary key that is a composition of, for example, `id` and `product`, than you will have to use either an `@EmbeddedId` or `@IdClass`.

Comment: @Id annotation mapped to private Integer productId solved my problem. Thank you. :)